# Mail server blacklist checker

Tags: email, dns

Is there a command line utility that checks if a specified mailserver is on some well-known [blacklist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL)?

I know [amispammer](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amispammer) but it is only available on Debian, it seems to be unmaintained and last time I checked it was very memory hungry.

Comment: Use the `host` command.

Comment: And not only very memory hungry, 46 dependencies to install? (...)

Comment: @IporSircer, for the occasional check of one IP address against one DNSBL manually reversing the address, concatenating it with the hostname of the list and querying the result with `host` or better `dig` is ok. But amispammer automates the querying of many lists.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, it's crazy, right? I've created a small Python 3 script that has just one dependency ... (cf. my answer).

Comment: That is one of the ways of doing it... I usually do more that kind of stuff in bash, have to use python more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I didn't find an amispammer substitute [I created `check-dnsbl.py`](https://github.com/gsauthof/utility#check-dnsbl), a small Python script that checks some well-known blacklists. It uses [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/) for all the necessary DNS requests.

Example:

```
$ ./check-dnsbl.py 117.246.201.146     
2016-11-05 19:01:13 - ERROR    - There is no reverse DNS record for 117.246.201.146
2016-11-05 19:01:13 - ERROR    - OMG, 117.246.201.146 is listed in DNSBL zen.spamhaus.org: 127.0.0.11 ("https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/117.246.201.146")
2016-11-05 19:01:19 - ERROR    - OMG, 117.246.201.146 is listed in DNSBL virbl.dnsbl.bit.nl: 127.0.0.2 ("See: http://virbl.bit.nl/lookup/index.php?ip=117.246.201.146")
2016-11-05 19:01:19 - ERROR    - 117.246.201.146 is listed in 2 blacklists
```

The `--debug` switch increases the verbosity, e.g.:

```
2016-11-05 20:19:21 - DEBUG    - Checking 26 DNS blacklists
```

(the set of blacklists can be changed via options - 2 of the default lists are aggregations)

It is also ok to just specify domain names:

```
$ ./check-dnsbl.py mailout1.example.org mailout2.example.org
```

Comment: When I ran an ISP I wrote once something similar running as an web page to cut down on the email tickets the helpdesk people escalated up.

Answer (score 2):

One of the simplest form of checking the presence of the IP address in a known blacklist is doing a DNS query either with `dig`, `host` or `nslookup` to an RBL/DNS list; after all is how email servers do it.

Namely several that are still very active, including:

- zen.spamhaus.org
- bl.spamcop.net
- cbl.abuseat.org

For instance to check if the IP address 116.103.227.39 is on a blacklist, you reverse it and add the reversed IP to one of the above lists.

```
$ host 39.227.103.116.zen.spamhaus.org.
39.227.103.116.zen.spamhaus.org has address 127.0.0.4
39.227.103.116.zen.spamhaus.org has address 127.0.0.11
```

From [DNS Blacklist (DNSBL / RBL) plug-in](http://simpledns.com/plugin-dnsbl)

> If the DNS lookup returns an value (typically the dummy IP address
>   127.0.0.2), this means that the sender's IP address is on the blacklist.